# Phantomjs - Is there a way to pass parameters to th

Tags: php, phantomjs

Let's say I have this code in PHP to call Phantomjs

`shell_exec("phantomjs a-phantomjs-file.js");`

Is there way to pass data from PHP to the phantomjs file? Some sort of commandline arguments perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of command line arguments for phantomjs here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference

You can use string concatenation or interpolation to pass them from PHP, just be aware of and careful to protect against injection attacks if the arguments could ever be coming from user input.

Comment: I see the list, but I don't see anything here that can help me pass some data from PHP to the phantomjs file

Comment: @arvinsim Do you mean that you want to edit the `phantomjs-file.js` file before you execute phantomjs? You could just open the file with fopen and edit it like you would normally edit a file in PHP.

Comment: Not really. What I had in mind is something like this: I have data from PHP like a uri. I want to pass that data to the phantomjs file that is going to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this.

```
 $array = array("option1"=>"Test", "option2"=>"test2"); // this is what you want in phantom
 $tmp = tempnam("/path/to/tempDir/", "PHANTOM_");
 file_put_contents($tmp, "var params = ".json_encode($array)."; ".file_get_contents("a-phantomjs-file.js"));
 shell_exec("phantomjs ".escapeshellarg($tmp));
 unlink($tmp);
```

Then in the phantom file you could access the properties as

```
 params.option1
```

Answer (score 1):

I send and receive data to and from PhantomJS with PHP like:

```
$command = '/path/to/phantomjs /path/to/my/script.js ' . escapeshellarg($uri);
$result_object = json_decode(shell_exec($command));
```

*WARNING: Be sure to untaint user input to prevent others from executing code on your server!*

Inside the javascript this URI variable is available as the second element of the `system.args` array (the first element is the name of the script you are calling):

```
var system = require('system');
var uri = system.args[1];
```

When your javascript is done you can output a JSON variable before exiting PhantomJS:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  "status": "success"
}));
phantom.exit();
```

In the first lines of the PHP code in this example we already used `json_decode()` to decode the plain text JSON return value into an object, so from within PHP we can access the `status` variable using:

```
print $result_object->status;
```