# use PhantomJS with PHP?

Tags: php, phantomjs

I am trying varuous PHP methods to 'get' a website & save the HTML output to a file on my server. However the URL I try contains javascript.

The HTML I see in my php script output is missig some content (created via Javascript on the URL I specify).

I have found something called PhantomJS, which apparently parses URL's with the 'processed' Javascript.

The examples i have found are incomplete & only show 1 part of the code at a time, without any full / useful working scripts.

Some issues

1) - i think i can do this part, not tested yet.

I can use the EXEC or SYSTEM commands to activate PhantomJS via my PHP script.

I've not tested, but I think i know how to send 2 variables to PhantomJS

http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html

guess:

```
address = system.args[1];
value = system.args[2];
```

phantomjs loadspeed.js http://www.google.com  56

(the 56 is the 2nd variable ) I guess i can pass several variables to PhantomJS.??

2) I am unable / have not found the answers to these as yet. can anyone assist.

a) Is it possible to save the HTML result of a website into a file I specify (one of the variables I pass to the script).

or

b) Pass the HTMl code back to the PHP script & save it into an array / variable.

Are there any good examples - Small, but WORKING scripts, of using phantom JS from a PHP script ?

Comment: There are a lot of hypothetical questions. Yes, it should work. Right now, you don't have anything where you would need assistence. Try something and we gladly help when you have a specific question. Here is a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24389078) that I found. You can look yourself through [those (php+phantomjs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+phantomjs) questions. To answer 2a: There is the [fs](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) module.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly got the issues you are facing I would recommend you do the following:

- 1) check [facebook-php-webdrive](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)r lib out
- 2) get phantomJs

A piece of example that you can use:

```
<?php
// An example of using php-webdriver.

require_once('lib/__init__.php');

// launching with GhostDriver

// remote host
//$host='http://162.243.175.134:8080';

//host launched on local machine
$host='http://127.0.0.1:8080';


$desired_capabilities =  DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($this->host,$desired_capabilities,5000);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');

// this way you're able to get page source
echo $driver->getPageSource();  


?>
```

actual result of `$driver->getPageSource();` function:
http://gyazo.com/4a5c4c1c378d7dc9714ddcc9e37b0174

As soon as you get page source to variable, you'll be able to save it  to file (on your server) or perform other actions with it.

I agree with  @Artjom B. that   [sending and receiving data to/from phantomJs with php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389078/1546574) is described pretty good.

Hope my ideas help you.

Regards.